# Update column based on duplicate columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables:

**account**

```
+----+---------------------+
| Id |        Email        |
+----+---------------------+
|  1 | "test@example.com"  |
|  2 | "test2@example.com" |
|  3 | "test3@example.com" |
|  4 | "test@example.com"  |
+----+---------------------+
```

**character**

```
+----+-----------+
| Id | AccountId |
+----+-----------+
|  1 |         1 |
|  2 |         1 |
|  3 |         2 |
|  4 |         3 |
|  5 |         4 |
+----+-----------+
```

`character.AccountId` is a FK to `account.Id`. Both `Id` columns are PK's to their respective tables.

I need to update the `character` table such that the new `AccountId` matches a row in `account` with the lowest account's `Id` but with the same `Email` as the currently set `AccountId`.

For example, in the mock data presented above all accounts have unique emails except account Id `1` and `4`, they both share `test@example.com` as email.

This means that after the update, the rows in the **character** table should stay the same except for the row with `Id = 5`, this row has an `AccountId = 4` and this account shares an email with an account that has a lower account Id, namely Id `1`. So the result output should be :

```
+----+-----------+
| Id | AccountId |
+----+-----------+
|  1 |         1 |
|  2 |         1 |
|  3 |         2 |
|  4 |         3 |
|  5 |         1 |
+----+-----------+
```

After the operation.

I've got this to work with a `TRIGGER BEFORE INSERT` on `character` to check if there are lower accountIds but can't get this to work with a simple `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE `character` SET `AccountId` = (SELECT MIN(Id) FROM `account` WHERE ?);
```

I've thought of maybe making a temporary table to store the account Id and the email with a `GROUP BY email` but this also fails. It being MySQL I can't use `MERGE` either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a window function to get the minimum id per email.  Then just join that in:

```
UPDATE character c JOIN
       (SELECT a.*,
               MIN(id) OVER (PARTITION BY a.email) as min_id
        FROM account a
       ) a
       ON c.accountId = a.id
    SET c.accountId = a.min_id
    WHERE c.accountId <> a.min_id;
```

Comment: `update character c inner join (select email, min(id) id from account group by email) b set c.accountId = b.id where c.accountId <> b.id;` if your mysql version don't support `partition by` Gordon beat me to it :)

Answer (score 1):

This is fairly straightforward without window functions, too; you want to find accounts with the same email and lower ids (the a2 join) and make sure you've got the lowest (the a3 join):

```
update `character` c
join account a on a.id=c.account_id
join account a2 on a2.email=a.email and a2.id < a.id
left join account a3 on a3.email=a2.email and a3.id < a2.id
set c.account_id=a2.id
where a3.id is null;
```

(As usual, the left join ... where ... is null could be replaced with a where not exists (...), if you prefer the query to show the intent more clearly instead of the probable query plan more clearly.)

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=9e16edf1d91c7b3c84a8c1317b002b61)